# File/folder permissions and ownership breaks wordpress functionality, what is a secure solution?

Tags: wordpress, apache, security, chmod, chown

I have a wordpress network running (on a shared host) to great satisfaction apart from a security dilemma.

When I first installed the application, I did this through a plesk Cpanel.
And later when I started to add plugins I realised the server used safe_mode On. I asked the host to remove it and they did but before this I did install most of my plugins through FTP because of permission problems due to the safe_mode On setting.

But now I seem to be running into a different setting that is limiting me. Because I installed plugins through FTP, my FTP user is the owner of the files. Now when I try to update through the normal wordpress routine, it doesn't have sufficient permission for the stream folder and when I set this to 777 it has not enough permission for the plugin folders because apache is not the owner of the folders and files.

I do not want to set all my folders to 777 (775 also doesn't work), changing owner (I tested with creating a folder through a Wordpress plugin) works, but http://codex.wordpress.org/Changing_File_Permissions tells me I shouldn't let apache be the owner of my files and folders.

Could you advise me about:

- security issues with regards to letting apache be the owner of my files and folders
- security issues with regards to 777 permissions (I think this is obvious a security risk, but perhaps I'm overlooking something)
- are there other things I could do to make wordpress function normally

If you need more information about the shared hosting, please let me know.

Answer (score 1):

I've run into similar problems in the past.

Ultimately, I found myself reading through the Hardening WordPress article on WordPress.org with a fine tooth comb and paying particular attention to this section: http://codex.wordpress.org/Hardening_WordPress#File_Permissions which recommends a mixture of 755 and 644.

You might want to run recursive changes (to make sure they echo out to the folders beneath), and then pop something like WordPress Firewall 2 on as a security plugin.

Ultimately, the shared hosting environment can only be secured to a certain level (because it's shared) - but both of those are a good start.

Comment: Thanks for the link, particularly 'Any file that needs write access from WordPress should be group-owned by the user account used by the web server.' looks to be what I'm looking for. Should I ask my host to add apache to the group?

Comment: Your user details should be enough - on a shared setup, using general Apache / system process details is a little bit risky (if you see the Permissions Scheme for WordPress writeup here: http://codex.wordpress.org/Changing_File_Permissions#Permission_Scheme_for_WordPress).

Comment: this bit sounds about right whats wrong in my case (weird sentence I know): "Any file that needs write access from WordPress should be owned or group-owned by the user account used by the WordPress". How can I make it so that wordpress can use my ftp account? I installed wordpress through my plesk cpanel.